# My sitecore licence got expired. Can I use other sitecore licence in the same sitecore instance

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

My sitecore(9.1) 60-day trial licence has got expired but i want to use some other active licence with the same instance of the sitecore. Is it possible? if yes, then what are the changes required to do. Please explain in detail.

Comment: Would be best to request an extension on your license. Once you receive the license simply copy over the old one an recycle the app pool.

Comment: @MichaelWest Can you please elaborate "recycle the app pool" ?

Comment: In IIS you can recycle the Application Pool for the given website.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible.

First, you must actually have a new license.

Secondly, make sure you replace the expired license file(s) on your Sitecore instance.

- If you are using Sitecore 8.x the old file is under `./Data`.
- If you are using Sitecore 9.0.x, then look at:

  - `.sc/App_Data`
  - `.xconnect/App_Data`
- If you are using Sitecore 9.1, then look at:

  - `.sc/App_Data`
  - `.xconnect/App_Data`
  - `.xconnect/jobs/continous/AutomationEngine/App_Data`
  - `.xconnect/jobs/continous/IndexWorker/App_Data`
  - `.xconnect/jobs/continous/ProcessingEngine/App_Data`

Comment: @Manjesh don't forget to accept this answer if you think it helped you solve the original problem.

Comment: And how to get a new license?

Comment: We need to contact your local Sitecore sales representative.